# mouseover and mouse out event use instead of click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a demo in which user click on any div .It will goes to top and set the background color text on label.Example If I click green it goes to top and write the text green on top.  But I need the same functionality using mouseover and mouse out  event .when user touch start and touch move or mouseover and mouse out  event it will rotate clockwise and anti clockwise and set the text on top .I make functionality which is running fine on click but i need mouseover and mouse out  so that I will rotate it clockwise and anti clockwise.
http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/cdZ73/3/

```
var arr = ["red","pink","blue","green"];

$('#full').on('click', 'div', function() {

    $('.colorName').text($(this).attr('class'));  

    //alert($(this).closest('#full').html());

    var sel = arr.indexOf($(this).attr('class'));

    $(this).closest('#full').find('div')
        .first().removeClass().addClass(arr[sel])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+1)%4])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+2)%4])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+3)%4]);

    //alert($(this).closest('#full').html());
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has two methods mouseover and mouseout;

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Below is an example of how you can add listeners to these events, I've not updated your function to do the rotation.

```
var arr = ["red","pink","blue","green"];

function doStuff(){
         $('.colorName').text($(this).attr('class'));  

        //alert($(this).closest('#full').html());

        var sel = arr.indexOf($(this).attr('class'));

        $(this).closest('#full').find('div')
            .first().removeClass().addClass(arr[sel])
            .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+1)%4])
            .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+2)%4])
            .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+3)%4]);

        //alert($(this).closest('#full').html());
}

$('#full').on('mouseout', 'div', doStuff);
$('#full').on('mouseover', 'div', doStuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this after click for the same effect when clicking:

```
$('#full').on('click mouseenter touchstart', 'div', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want the same effect on mouseover/mouseout.

Just add an handler on the event, like that

```
$('#full div').hover(function(){
    $('.colorName').text($(this).attr('class')); 

    var sel = arr.indexOf($(this).attr('class'));

    $(this).closest('#full').find('div')
        .first().removeClass().addClass(arr[sel])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+1)%4])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+2)%4])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+3)%4]);

}, function(){
    return false;
})
```

Or, like [Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2992661/dean-whitehouse) said, just close everything into a function and add the right event handlers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

The `click` event is fine. So to deal only with `mouseover` and `mouseout` let's use CSS and `:hover` pseudo-class!

```css
#full div {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1000ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1000ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1000ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1000ms ease-out;
    transition: transform 1000ms ease-out;
}
#full div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Here's your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cdZ73/11/)**